# ts-jest limitation in namespaces support

Tags: ts-jest

According to [the documentation](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/babel7-or-ts/#no-namespace) `ts-jest` doesn't support namespaces. What does it mean exactly?

I'm trying to convert [this tutorial](https://dalste.co.uk/tutorial-getting-started-typescript-cocos2d-x-js-part-2-tslint-mocha) from Mocha to `ts-jest`. It is written with TypeScript namespaces:

> Most modern TypeScript guides will use external modules, but for our purposes and to simplify the compatibility with Cocos2d-x jsb we will use namespaces and triple slash directives.

It looks like `ts-jest` can't parse below `greet.test.ts` file:

```
/// <reference path="./greet.ts" />

import sayHello = typescriptbase.sayHello;
```

```
 FAIL  src/greet.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: typescriptbase is not defined

       9 |
    > 10 | import sayHello = typescriptbase.sayHello;
         |
```

Where `greet.ts` is:

```
namespace typescriptbase {
    export function sayHello(name: string) {
        return `Hello from ${name}`;
    }
}
```

Is that because of `ts-jest` not supporting namespaces?

Comment: Those are limitations _of `@babel/preset-typescript`_, not of `ts-jest`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error you're encountering is due to ts-jest's limitation in supporting namespaces. ts-jest is designed to work primarily with the ES module system, which is the most common and modern way of organizing TypeScript and JavaScript code.

In case you would like to still change your code to ts-jest I would suggest you refactor your code to use ES modules instead of namespaces.